# Javascript change case for input value

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm learning Javascript so please excuse me for such a newbie question. I'm trying to remove space from the input value string after converted its Case. I thought it would work with the replace method, but I guess there is something missing.

HTML

```
<input type= "text" id="city2check">
<button type="submit" onClick="myCity()">Check</button>
```

JS

```
<script>         
function myCity() {    

    var cleanestCities = ["Cheyenne", "Santa Fe", "Tucson", "Great Falls", "Honolulu"];   

    var check = city2check.value;

    var firstChar = check.slice(0,1);    
    var otherChar = check.slice(1);    
    firstChar = firstChar.toUpperCase();
    otherChar = otherChar.toLowerCase();    
    var checkcity = firstChar + otherChar;

    checkcity.replace(/ /g, '');


    var matchfound = false;    
        for (var i = 0; i < cleanestCities.length; i++) {

            if (checkcity === cleanestCities[i]) {
                matchfound = true;
                alert("correct");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (matchfound === false) {
            alert("sorry not correct");
            //code
        }
    }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LVXTB/1/

Comment: Two of your cities have spaces in the names.

Comment: Also the `.replace()` function **returns** the altered string; it does not change the original string.

Comment: I'm trying to see if I can remove the spaces from those two cities so that when user inputs the value, it checks from the array. does it make sense?

Comment: As a side note, an easier to do letter case, is just to have all lowercase in your array and then convert the input to lowercase altogether

Comment: @Huangism, easier for whom, the programmer or the user? Make the computer adjust to human spelling, not the other way around. The values for `cleanestCities` will not be hard-coded by the programmer in real-life. These values are typically stored in a database and entered by users, just normal people that aren't going to spell Santa Fe with some funky version like "santafe". Plus, those values typically get used for other applications, so you want them spelled and capitalized correctly.

Comment: @JonathanM that's what my answer does, converts user input and kills spaces to match the array. You want to leave the array as is then convert it to lowercase and kill spaces before compare

Comment: @Huangism, your answer requires funky, non-human spellings and capitalizations in the `cleanestCities` array. That's not good in real-life practice.

Comment: @JonathanM already addressed it in my prev comments. For the question at hand, it is more efficient on the js to do it this way. Sure you could leave the array and run the replace and toLowerCase on `cleanestCities[i]`

Comment: @Huangism, that's my point: more efficient for the programmer, not the user maintaining the database that might be populating the list of cleanestCities.

Comment: @JonathanM I understand where you are coming from, but for this question there is no database involved. I also mentioned the fix for that in the comments of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of logical errors, this is the working one

When comparing, I changed all city names to lowercase in your array and I got rid of the space for the array. If you just replace all the spaces in the input then it will never match the 2 word city since in your array there is a space. If you define your array without space, it would save the replace operation during the compare (see http://jsfiddle.net/LVXTB/9/).

Cleaned version http://jsfiddle.net/LVXTB/12/

```
function myCity() {    

    var cleanestCities = ["cheyenne", "santafe", "tucson", "greatfalls", "honolulu"];   

    var checkcity = city2check.value.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');
    var matchfound = false;    

    var l = cleanestCities.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (checkcity === cleanestCities[i]) {
            matchfound = true;
            alert("correct");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (matchfound === false) {
        alert("sorry not correct");
        //code
    }
}
```

In your original code, you convert the first letter to caps and the rest to lowercase, so any 2 word city will not match since you have uppercase in the second word in your array.

When you replaced space with nothing, any 2 word city will not match since in your array you have a space.

Also `checkcity.replace(/ /g, '');` does not assign the value of the result of the replace. The main issue is you converted all characters to lowercase but the first.

If the array has a mix case then you can do

```
if (checkcity === cleanestCities[i].toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '')) {
```

Comment: ok what if the array values are like (Great Falls or Santa Fe) mix of upper and lower case?

Comment: then you just need to convert all of them to lowercase when comparing `checkcity === cleanestCities[i].toLowerCase()` if you want the safest compare then convert all values to lowercase and get rid of all spaces (input and array)

Comment: The problem with this approach is no one hard codes the acceptable values in real life. They are typically entered into a database by real people who are not going to spell Santa Fe as "santafe". A solution that makes the computer adjust to human spelling rather than the other way around is preferable. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better version of your function that deals properly with spaces and title case, especially for two-word cities.

```
function myCity() {    

    var cleanestCities = ["Cheyenne", "Santa Fe", "Tucson", "Great Falls", "Honolulu"];   

    var checkcity = city2check.value;
    checkcity=checkcity.replace(/  +$/g, '');
    checkcity=checkcity.replace(/^  +/g, '');
    checkcity=checkcity.replace(/ +/g, ' ');
    checkcity=checkcity.replace(/([^\W_]+[^\s-]*) */g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});

    var matchfound = false;    
        for (var i = 0; i < cleanestCities.length; i++) {

            if (checkcity === cleanestCities[i]) {
                matchfound = true;
                alert("correct");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (matchfound === false) {
            alert("sorry not correct");
            //code
        }
}
```

Using this code, type, for instance, "     santa    fe    ", and it will clean it up appropriately.

http://jsfiddle.net/LVXTB/14/